# Need help customizing mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is my current trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` TRIGGER `unique_visit_new_campaign` AFTER INSERT ON `unique_visit` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE pixel_id int;
    DECLARE campaign_id varchar(45);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM pixels;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur;
            ins_loop: LOOP
                FETCH cur INTO pixel_id;
                IF done THEN
                    LEAVE ins_loop;
                END IF;
                INSERT IGNORE INTO pixels_campaign (campaign_id , pixel_id , date) VALUES (NEW.campaign_id ,pixel_id, current_timestamp);
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur;
END
```

I need it to **NOT TRIGGER** when new.campaign_id is empty or equals to the string {campaign_id}

I tried using MySQL IF but with no success.

Also, It kinda auto increment even when there is a campaign id already (when it ignores). any way I can stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` TRIGGER `unique_visit_new_campaign` AFTER INSERT ON `unique_visit` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE pixel_id int;
    DECLARE campaign_id varchar(45);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM pixels;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    IF new.campaign = '' or new.campaign = '{campaign_id}' or new.campaign is null THEN

        OPEN cur;
                ins_loop: LOOP
                    FETCH cur INTO pixel_id;
                    IF done THEN
                        LEAVE ins_loop;
                    END IF;
                    INSERT IGNORE INTO pixels_campaign (campaign_id , pixel_id , date) VALUES (NEW.campaign_id ,pixel_id, current_timestamp);
                END LOOP;
            CLOSE cur;
    END IF

END
```